# How an user can access permissions on information_schema.columns of postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I created one user like below.

```
create role testuser1 with password 'testuser1' login; 
 alter role testuser1 with createrole createdb;
```

Now I login into postgres using the above user like below

```
psql -U testuser1 -d template1
```

I got template1 command prompt. Like below

```
template1#
```

After this, I create one sample database like below

template# create database testdb;
I was succesfully created db. Now, I exit from postgres. And again I tried to login with sample credentials, but with the database testdb and tried to import schema file(let it be test.sql) using below command

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U testuser1 -d testdb -f "/mnt/hgfs/shared_ubuntu/sample_test_schema/pg/test.sql"
```

It's imported successfully.  After this in testdb , the below is the tables.

```
 Schema |    Name    | Type  |  Owner   
--------+------------+-------+----------
 public | pretabinto | table | postgres
 public | serial     | table | postgres
 public | temp       | table | postgres
```

Now, I tried to get tables and it's columns info using the below query. But, I am getting 0 list.

```
SELECT table_name,column_name,data_type 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');
```

How should I get columns info using the above user (like newly created user).

Comment: You need to create new `database` with the template name `template0`. See the manual http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html By default it is `template1`.

Answer (score 9):

Users can only see data in the COLUMNS table of INFORMATION_SCHEMA for tables on which they have read permissions.  So the thing you need to do is:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA PUBLIC TO testuser2;
```

Also, I suggest NOT using the template1 database for "scratch space".  That database is used as a template for creating other databases, which means you'll have lots of garbage in each database you create hereafter.  I suggest using the "postgres" database we provide as a test database instead.

Comment: I am getting error in greenplum.   ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ALL"
LINE 1: GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA PUBLIC TO neeraj;
                        ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "ALL"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 17

Comment: Yes, that's because Greenplum is based on PostgreSQL 8.1, which was before we added "GRANT ON ALL".  Unfortunately, you're going to have to grant permissions on each view/function individually.  :-(

Comment: Actually,I want to select information_schema.schemata view from another users however after select grant i am not able to get the data.

Comment: select runs successfully but no data appears.@fuzzychef any suggession

Comment: Maybe post a new, actual question? It's been years since I did anything with Greenplum, so you'll be better off if someone else answers it.